# Validate domain name PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to validate domain names using PHP.
Only this format should be allowed: `google.com`, `subdomain.stack-overflow.org` etc
It should only allow - (in case of special characters)

No other format should be allowed ex: `http, https,?,/index.php,www.` etc (none of these should be allowed).

Also i do not want to allow: `localhost`,`mydomain.com`

I have tried: `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` but it accepts `http` etc.
I also tried something regular expression like this:  `[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)`

But it is allowing ex: `stackoverflow`  (without a `.org`).

How can I achieve that?

```
$urlparts = parse_url(filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
if(!isset($urlparts['host'])){
    $urlparts['host'] = $urlparts['path'];
}
```

Comment: So `help.me is having problems` is valid ?

Comment: Why not use FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, then use str_replace to remove the http?

Comment: @RichBradshaw: Because then `http://example.com/page` is also allowed.

Comment: @RichBradshaw - `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` accepts any kind of URL, not only HTTP, and doesn't impose restrictions on the host name (so `localhost` would not be filtered out as the OP wants).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario This is a very valid point, i do not want to allow localhost, mydomain.com

Comment: Why can't you query the dns records?

Comment: @PeeHaa I just need to validate a name. Thanks

Comment: @sash I've just linked to the non-accepted answer and it works for your case, see a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/sN2vY7).

Comment: @HamZa Thank you, i'm testing it!

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression was nearly correct.  Just the `.` is short for "any character", not just for ".". So, try this regex:

```perl
/([0-9a-z-]+\.)?[0-9a-z-]+\.[a-z]{2,7}/
```

Remember that new top level domains are introduced. They do not use latin characters.  Take a look at http://many.at/idntlds/.

About excluding “mydomain.com”: You would have to check for this after applying the regular expression.

Comment: Thank you, i'm trying this. Please check question i have edited it , i want to allow subdomains like subdomain.stack-overflow.org  also.   Thanks a lot

Comment: Want to allow sub-subdomains as well, like “user.server.domain.tld”?

Comment: No i want to allow sub domains only. But the domain should not be localhost or mydomain.com